# change the url paths in the stylesheet dynamically

Tags: functions, css

Hello I found a function that when placed in the functions.php, it injects the entire stylesheet into the head on the website:

```
add_action( 'wp_head', 'internal_css_print' );
function internal_css_print() {
  echo '<style>';

  include_once get_template_directory() . '/style.css';

  echo '</style>';
}
```

It works great, the whole stylesheet goes in the head just fine, but one minor issue is that the urls in the css are broken. For example when the following is in the css file:

```
background: url('images/hero-desktop.jpg');
```

When the stylesheet is linked normally, this returns `http://localhost:8888/wp-content/themes/my-theme/images/hero-desktop.jpg`-> works

But when the stylesheet is injected in the head it returns: `http://localhost:8888/images/hero-desktop.jpg` --> doesnt work. The path is broken.

To fix this I can do a simple search and replace in the css to change `url('` to `url('/wp-content/themes/my-theme/` but there has to be a better way.

So I was thinking is there something to add to the function at the top, so before spitting out the whole css file into the head, it dynamically changes the url path. If this is possible that would be great so its just a one time setup instead of searching and replacing css on an already developed site.

Thanks!

Comment: injecting CSS directly into the page means you'll be delivering that page weight for every page rather than browsers just grabbing a CSS file directly from local cache, not sure why you'd want to do this.

Comment: i agree with that statement, but at my agency we are focused on page speed, and google pagespeed scores improve when the css is in the head some reason